# Applying animation more than once in android

Tags: android, animation

I have a problem with applying an animation

Given the following animation code

```
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_10"
        android:toXDelta="10" />
```

after starting the application this animation can be applied only once

```
public void onClick{
button.setAnimation(shake);
}
```

how to apply this animation more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View.startAnimation(Animation) ?

Comment: YEP))Nice
But what difference between setAnimation method and startAnimation really don't understand ??

Comment: i always encourage people in reading the source code, so take View.java into your editor and you will find everything

Answer (score 0):

add following lines in animation xml-

```
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
```